# Форма контроля категорий

Tags: php

Я хочу реализовать добавление товара в категории . Сейчас всё работает но я бы хотел видеть определённые несколько названий категорий а не все сразу категории в контроллере.
Как его можно будет отфильтровать что бы только нужные мне категории были активны ?

```
'<label>Категория:</label><?php
echoisset 
($error['category_ID'])? 
$error['category_ID']: 
'';?>
<select 
name="category_ID"
class="form-control">
<?php while 
($stmt_category->fetch 
()){?> 
<option value="<?php 
 echo
$category_data['Category_ID'];
?>"><?phpecho 
$category_data['Category_name'];
?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил это.
вот так:

```
<div id="content" class="container col-md-12">
<?php 
    $sql_query = "SELECT Category_ID , Category_name 
        FROM tbl_category
        WHERE Category_ID IN (47,50,48,52)
        ORDER BY Category_ID ASC";

    $stmt_category = $connect->stmt_init();
    if($stmt_category->prepare($sql_query)) {   
        // Execute query
        $stmt_category->execute();
        // store result 
        $stmt_category->store_result();
        $stmt_category->bind_result($category_data['Category_ID'], 
            $category_data['Category_name']
            );      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял:

Можно сделать массив с желаемыми категориями

```
$myCategories = array('нужная категория'=>1, 'другая нужная категория' => 1);
```

И при выводе делать проверку по типу:

```
//Если текущая категория в цикле есть в массиве категорий для отображения
    if ($myCategories[$category_data['Category_name']]) {
       echo $category_data['Category_name'];
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я нашёл решение.